# Methods for NPC Relationship Diagrams

Tags: npc, relationship-mechanic

I am trying to find a good method to build Relationship Diagrams.  So a tool or other method that can automatically generate a diagram showing the relationships between NPCs.  When I say relationships, I don't mean a simple pedigree diagram.  It would have connecting lines for friendships et cetera.

If you know of an article that gives tips on how to make these manually, I'd be open to that as well.

[This is an example of the type of diagram I am referring to.](https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7358/8732223668_32c280a488_b.jpg)

I'm not looking for something fancy, in fact if it were php code I'd be happy.

If this a specific type of relationship diagram, please let me know that as well.

Comment: Thanks for the duplicate link.  Just goes to show how much you search, you don't always find what you need.

Comment: Asking duplicates, which get linked to the main question, helps future searchers find it. So thank you for the duplicate. :) Incidentally, these kinds of diagrams are most often called “relationship maps”, or “R-maps” for short.